# double pointers error in C when compiling error when using void as well

Tags: c, pointers, double

I'm new to C and im currently learning about pointers.

I'm  not sure why I am getting an error with the following sections of code in regards to pointers :

```
char ch;     
char** pointer;    
pointer = &ch;
```

and

```
int function1(void) 
{
  return 42.0;
}

void function2(void) 
{
  void (*pointer)(int);
  pointer = &function1;
  ...
}
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: On the first section, you shouldn't have a double pointer, just a simple pointer

Comment: oh yeah the double pointer im very new to that, thank you :) how do i fix the second one

Comment: `void (*pointer)(int);` should be `int (*pointer)(void);`

Comment: The second one should be `int(*pointer)(void)`

Comment: Please take a bit time to follow simple rules when asking questions. If there are errors or warnigns, then show us. Show the exact message and the exact code.

Comment: sorry @Gerhardh im new to stack overflow :) just getting the hang of it. will do that next time of course :)

Answer (score 1):

The very first problem is that you are using a double pointer in `char** pointer` ,as you are not storing the address of some other pointer so you should use `char *pointer` instead.
Then your function1 has return type as `int` but you are returning a `float` value ,although it won't give you any error but it can create some logical issues in your program,so better to properly write the return type in function definition and its prototype.
Then the next problem is in the `function2`,your `function1` returns `int` but does not take any arguments but your function pointer return void and take int ,so you should better modify this to

```
int (*pointer)(void);
```

and then store the address of `function1` in `pointer` ,it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a single pointer and `**` is a pointer to pointer.
So instead of

```
char** pointer;
```

It should be:

```
char* pointer;
```

In the second case, the function pointer prototype is not matching the prototype of the function it is pointing to.

So instead of

```
void (*pointer)(int);
```

it should be:

```
int (*pointer)(void);
```

Answer (score 0):

you second section have some mistakes

you `function1()` return `int` and not take args

but your fucntion ptr return `void` and take `int`

so change it to:

```
int (*pointer)(void);

pointer = &function1;
```